# How to print this Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>(); on Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, logcat

I'm developing an app and I need to print this type of data

`Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

How could I print it in the logcat console?

Comment: `params.toString()` does not do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the Android log utility

```
import android.util.Log;
```

Then it's as simple as

```
Log.d("AnyTagYouWant", params.toString());
```

LinkedHashMap (like all AbstractMap subclasses) displays all its keys and values in its `toString` method.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a for loop with printlns.

```
Set<String> keys = params.keySet();
for (String s : keys){
   System.out.println(params.get(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That very much depends on your requirements.

A simple `System.out.println(someMap);` will already print the content of that map.

You can of course iterate the entries of the map, using `getEntrySet()` to print those individually.